# Limit and sequence, why is it an indeterminate form?

Tags: limits

Can anyone explain why in limits of sequences $\bigl[\infty - \infty\bigr]$ and $\bigl[\frac{\infty}{\infty}\bigr]$ are indeterminate forms?

Comment: Take care : **success** (in the title) is evidently not **succession** ; btw, what is succession doing here ?

Comment: Note that Italian “successione” is *sequence* in English and “forme di indecisione” are usually called *indeterminate forms*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they can become whatever, depending on the details of how the two conflicting $\infty$'s are approached. We simply do not have enough information to conclude anything. For instance, for the first one, we could have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}2n - n
$$
which is clearly of type $[\infty-\infty]$, and the limit is $\infty$. However, we might just as well have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}n-2n
$$
which gives $-\infty$. For anything in-between, we may use $\lim_{n\to \infty}(n+a) - n$, which gives $a$. Thus, just from the information that our limit is of the type $[\infty - \infty]$, we can't tell anything about what the limit actually is. Contrast this with, for instance, $[\infty + \infty]$ or $[\infty + 0]$, which necessarily gives $\infty$.

The same happens with $\left[\frac\infty\infty\right]$, using $\frac{n^2}{n}$, $\frac{n}{n^2}$ and $\frac{an}{n}$ as examples, although in this case we can actually tell that whatever the limit is (if it exists), it must be non-negative. However, anything more than that is impossible without more information. Other typical indecidable forms are $[0^0], [1^\infty]$, $[\infty\cdot 0]$ and $[\frac00]$ (and you can even translate between all of these indecidable forms by using logarithms, exponentials and fraction laws, so in a sense, they're all equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

The limit $\lim_{x\to+\infty}x-x$ is of the type $\infty-\infty$. But $x-x=0$ and so the limit is $0$. But $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(x+1)-x$, which is also of the type $\infty-\infty$, is equal to $1$. This is why $\infty-\infty$ is an indeterminate.